# Assembly - Program does not return anything

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have been tearing my hairs out learning assembly haha. I am trying to get the program to do the following computation: 2^3 + 5^2.

I tried to debug with gdb, but I don't understand much at all and internet searches don't reveal much. 
This program is for x86-64. The program compiles fine , but after typing `echo $?`, I expected `33` but got `0` instead.

Here is the code:

```
  1 .section .data
  2 .section .text
  3 .globl _start
  4 _start:
  5         pushq $3 #push the 2nd arg
  6         pushq $2 #push the 1st arg
  7 
  8         call power #call function
  9         addq $16, %rsp #move stack back 16 bytes to get rid of first two params
 10 
 11         pushq %rax #save the first answer before
 12 
 13         pushq $2 #push the 2nd arg
 14         pushq $5 #push the 1st arg
 15 
 16         call power #call function
 17         addq $16, %rsp #move stack back 16 bytes to get rid of first two params
 18         popq %rbx #2nd answer already in rax. We saved saved first answer onto stack and now pop it into rbx.
 19 
 20         addq %rax, %rbx #add together
 21 
 22         movq $60, %rax #exit
 23         syscall
 24 
 25 .type power, @function
 26 power:
 27         pushq %rbp #save old base pointer
 28         movq %rsp, %rbp #make stack pointer base pointer
 29         subq $8, %rsp #get room for local storage
 30 
 31         movq 16(%rbp), %rbx #put 1st arg in rbx
 32         movq 24(%rbp), %rcx # put 2nd arg in rbx
 33 
 34         movq %rbx, -8(%rbp) #store current result
 35 
 36 power_loop_start:
 37         cmpq $1, %rcx #if power is one, we are done
 38         je end_power #jump to end_power
 39 
 40         movq -8(%rbp), %rax #move current result into rax
 41         imulq %rbx, %rax #multiply current result by base number
 42 
 43         movq %rax, -8(%rbp) #store the current result
 44         decq %rcx #decrease the power
 45 
 46         jmp power_loop_start
 47 
 48 end_power:
 49         movq -8(%rbp), %rax #return value back to rax
 50         movq %rbp, %rsp #restore stack pointer
 51         popq %rbp #restore base pointer
 52         retq
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you wish to return the resulted value as exit code, you'd store the result into register `rdi` as the argument for system call `exit`. In short, please add below line at line#21 : 
`movq %rbx, %rdi`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I've been killing myself over this simple thing!!! I thought there was something wrong with the logic!

Comment: By the way, why do we have to use rdi? I converted this from 32 bit and in that version, I simple added eax to ebx to get the value returned as exit code.

Comment: for i386 arch, the calling convention is: `ebx`=arg1, `ecx`=arg2, ... , while for x86_64 arch: `rdi`=arg1, `rsi`=arg2, ...   you may check http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux for detail.